# Connecting $.post with hash.split and outputting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help connecting these two scripts with each other and outputting the result in that profile.php file.

Also, is it safe and will it even output profile.php hash?

```
var parts = window.location.hash.split('/');
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

**with**

```
p: function(){
 $.post("profile.php", function(profile) {
        $('#result').html(profile);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your PHP file does'nt have access to the location hash, so how exactly do you intend to pass the hash to the serverside, as data or... ?

Comment: I'm so confused. Please explain better.

Comment: I'm looking for sending hash to the server side and later print it out with $_POST[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information about the application, it's hard to be sure what you need, but it's probably something like:

```
p: function() {
    var parts = window.location.hash.split('/');
    var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
    $.post("profile.php", {
        id: id
    }, function(profile) {
        $('#result').html(profile);
    });
}
```

This sends the ID in the hash to profile.php as `$_POST['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the id which are striping from the hash url

```
$.post("profile.php", { "id": id })
.done(function(profile) {
  $('#result').html(profile);
});
```